# How Do You Fix the Darkened Text Selection Color in Safari? - CSS

Tags: html, css, safari, selection, pseudo-element

I have been using the following CSS code on my website to change the color of selected text, and it seems to work on every browser except Safari. Please let me know what should be added as the Safari Browser seems to darken whatever color I choose, unlike other browsers:

```
<style>
    ::selection {
        background-color: #003200;
        color: #fff8dc;
}
```

Comment: on IOS Safari or Safari browser?

Comment: Can you include the full code, and specially a [mre] ?

Comment: I’m fairly new to coding and have implemented this code as a snippet into the body - end section of the custom code area available for Wix websites through the dashboard. This snippet seems to work for most browsers, and I added a ::-moz-selection for Firefox, but for some reason the color of selected text for the browser version of Safari is made much darker, making my chosen background color appear black!

Comment: If there is a way to override the Safari Browser’s darkening of the selection color, I would love to know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this issue described [here](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/6853)

For now you can make your background-color 99% opacity

```
::selection {
  background-color: rgba(0, 50, 0, 0.99);
  color: #fff8dc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to solve the the issue

Comment: Using `calc(254 / 255)` instead of `0.99` is probably a slightly better option to get closer to being fully opaque (254 instead of 252). You can also append `fe` to a six-digit color code, like `#ff0000` -> `#ff0000fe`.